# Как добавить стиль во все приложение?

Tags: android, xml

```
    <style name="EditTextOval">
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_oval</item>
</style>
```

Я хочу добавить в Тему `MainTheme` данный стиль. Чтобы все EditText которые есть в приложении имели стиль EditTextOval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Базовая тема `AppTheme` и ваш стиль для `EditText`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
   <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextOval</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextOval" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_oval</item>
</style>
```

В тэг `application` манифеста

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Comment: `android:editTextStyle` Не работает. А `editTextStyle` вот так работает. Но почему `<item name="android:layout_marginLeft">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">50dp</item>` не применяются?

Comment: На вопрос я ответил :) насчет этого - скорее всего проблема в разметке

Comment: Тогда еще вопрос. как можно изменить цвет через Tint у DrawableLeft в EditText. В АПИ 19. tint работает лишь с 23

Comment: Слушайте, один вопрос = один ответ. Задайте еще один, ибо так нельзя